# how to solve $2^x \bmod 53 ≡ 1$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was writing network security exam, one of the question is $2^x \bmod 53 ≡ 1$ where x is a non-zero integer.
This they asked because most of the encryption and decryption algorithms involves modulus calculation

Comment: For completeness, I suppose the trivial solution $x=0$ should also be mentioned...

Comment: There are more than 1 non-trivial solution. For a solution x, $2^{x^n}$ is also 1 mod 53

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $53$ is prime, consider [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermats_little_theorom),
$$a^p \equiv a \quad \mod p$$
Or equivalently
$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \mod p \quad (\text{since $53$ doesn't divide $2$})$$

Answer (score 2):

By Fermat's little theorem $2^{52}\equiv 1 \bmod 53$, since $p=53$ is prime. Now smaller $x$ are not possible (just test it).

Answer (score 0):

The order of $2$ mod $53$ must be a divisor of $\phi(53)=52$. The only possibilities are then $1,2,4,13,26,52$. You can quickly test all the possibilities to see that the order is $52$. Thus the congruence is satisfied when $52|x$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: porve that $$2^{13}\equiv 30 \mod 53$$ and $$2^{26}\equiv -1 \mod 53$$

Answer (score 0):

As $(2,53)=1$ using Fermat's Little Theorem, $2^{53-1}\equiv1\pmod{53}$

But $53-1=52$ may not the smallest exponent $d,$ such that $2^d\equiv1\pmod{53}$

We can prove $d\mid52\implies d\in\{1,2,4,13,26,52\}$

Clearly, $d\nmid4$

$2^8\equiv-9\implies2^{13}=2^5\cdot2^8\equiv32(-9)\pmod{53}\equiv-23$

$\implies2^{26}=(2^{13})^2\equiv(-23)^2\equiv-1\implies d\nmid26$